# Basic awk question regarding including a space in the FS with an escaped character

Tags: regex, bash, awk

Please forgive the basic question.  I have read a large number of related threads and haven't stumbled upon a working solution.

Just need to grab the contents of a string between a "[ " and " ]".  Note the spaces in there.

code:

```
echo "*** This is a bunch of text output [ xxxxxxxxxx ]." | awk -F "[\\\[|\\\]]" '{print $2}'
 xxxxxxxxxx
```

I end up with a leading and trailing space on the output.  I've tried so many different variations in an attempt to get either a literal or regex match to include the square bracket *and* space together as the FS, but have not succeeded.  I'm sure I'm missing something super basic as this is really new to me.

I suppose I could remove the leading and trailing spaces as a second operation, but it seems like I should be able to accomplish it within the awk statement if I could get the FS format correct.

Thanks!

Comment: use single quotes around the `-F` argument so you don't have to double the backslashes.

Comment: When I use the single quotes, I still have to use double backslashes (not triple though), or I get `awk: warning: escape sequence `\]' treated as plain `]'`

Comment: That's a separate issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `*` before and after the `[\[\]]` to match the spaces. Also, you don't need `|` in the character set.

```
echo "*** This is a bunch of text output [ xxxxxxxxxx ]." | awk -F ' *[][] *' -v '{print $2}'
```

Also, `awk` doesn't support escaped `[` and `]` inside character classes. The way to include these characters is to put `]` at the beginning -- you can't have an empty character set, so this indicates that it's an actual character rather than the end of the set.

Comment: Oooh.  I like this one.  That's what I was looking for... thanks!  Question:  after I saw this answer I went and looked up what -v OFS= does, and I'm not sure about this context.  When I run the line it doesn't seem to make a difference in the output if I include it or not.  Can you give me just a brief explanation of why it's included?

Comment: @BlueSideUp The code doesn't use OFS so the only reason to include it would be to show how to set it if you had to.

Comment: @Barmar `[..]` in POSIX terminology is a bracket expression, not a character class. A character class is, for example, `[:space:]`. I know there's other non-POSIX terminology but it gets very vague/muddy/ambiguous around those 2 concepts (I've seen it refering to all 3 of  `[:space:]` and `[a-z]` and `[[:space:][a-z]]` as "character classes") so it's best avoided and just stick to POSIX terminology. Whatever you call it though, some awks such as GNU awk and OSX awk do support escaped `[` and `]` inside it, you just have to double up the escapes when using them in a string like `-F '[x\\]y]'`.

Comment: You're right that `[]xy]` is the more portable, POSIX way to include `]` in a bracket expression though. The warning the OP got about `awk: warning: escape sequence ]' treated as plain ]'` was due to the wrong number of escapes - `[\\\]...]` is escaping the escape once and then escaping the `]` once when they should have been doing `[\\]...]` to escape the `]`twice but they also made it much worse by using double quotes instead of single which opened it up to shell interpretation before awk interpretation so they'd need to add even more escapes! `-F '[\\[|\\]]'` would have avoided the warning.

Comment: @BlueSideUp Sorry, OFS was left over from some debugging I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i came up with.

```
echo "*** This is a bunch of text output [ xxxxxxxxxx ]." | awk -F'[][ ]+' '{print $(NF-1)}'
```